# For Dynamics CRM 365 Security Roles what Does Append and Append To Mean?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 the security roles have an "Append" and "Append To" rights. What does "Append" and "Append To" mean and what is the difference between them?

I googled for the answer, but cannot find a definitive one.

Comment: Please note that I meant "Append" and "Append To" rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append and Append To are two privileges that most user are not very clear about regarding their functionality. In this article we try to explain the difference between “Append” and “Append To” Privileges and how it affects the user access.

Append and Append To basically deal with the entities that are parties to a 1:N relationship or N:1 relationship.

Append: When an entity has the lookup of another entity on its form. It is important that the user has the “Append” privilege on this entity so that it can set the values for the lookups on this entity. For eg: Contact has the lookup of Account on its form so here the user needs to have the “Append” privilege to be able to set the parent account.

Append To: When an entity is available as a lookup on another entity form. It is important that the user has the “Append to” privilege on the entity that is referred to in the lookup so that it can set the values for the lookups of this entity on any other form. For eg: Account has the lookup of primary contact. So here the user needs to have the “Append To” privilege to be able to set the Primary Contact for the Account.

Lets us take an example of Contact entity.

We have modified the Order Role and removed the “append” privilege to the Contact entity.

[image]

When a user with this role logs in, they would find the Parent Account lookup disabled.

[image]

This is because the user does not have the “Append” privilege to the contact entity. So all the lookups on the contact form are Disabled.

Now we have modified the Order Role and provided the “Append” privilege for the contact entity and removed the “Append To” privilege from the contact entity.

[image]

The Primary Contact on Account is disabled.

[image]

It means the lookup of contact entity will be disabled on all the entities if the “append to” privilege to contact is removed.

Reference for the blog: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2010/05/03/append-v-47-s-append-to

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't find anything because there is no concept called "Assign" and "Assign To" rights.

We have "Assign", "Append" and "Append To" privileges.

Assignment is nothing but changing the owner lookup value of the entity record from user A (or Team X) to user B (or Team Y).

Excerpt of better definition for **Append** and **AppendTo**:

> One way of thinking conceptually about Append and Append To is to think of ‘Append Me‘ and ‘Append To Me‘.
>
> In order to successfully append record A to record B, the security privileges must be set to allow both sides of the agreement. Consider the following metaphor, Append ‘knocks on the door’ of another entity and Append To is needed to ‘open the door’ to that entity. For example, if you want to qualify an Account and begin working the opportunity as set in your business process flow, you must have to rights to append the Account (record A) and the rights to append to the opportunity (record B).

[Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2015/03/18/definitions-append-and-append-to-dynamics-crm/)

Comment: Thanks Arun. Another example: To stick a post-it note to a refrigerator, you'd need Append rights on the note and Append To rights on the refrigerator.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that they are Append and Append To.

Comment: @glennsep happy to help

Comment: @ArunVinoth-MVP Actually I have been testing Append and Append To in Dynamics CRM 2016 to see the minimum permissions required to create users in a Business Unit. I noticed that Only 'Append To' in the Business Unit is required, and no 'Append' is required in the user entity. I also noticed that even if I have a lower Append To access level in the Business Unit, but I have a wider Read access level, I will still be able to create users in Business Units where my Append To access level isn't covering. I wonder if these are bugs.